# How to log custom errors in scheduled job execution within Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a stored procedure that runs every day, my problem is... if this procedure finds any controlled error, how do I log this into "Aditional Info(Run)/Errors/Output" columns on the run log of my scheduled job (I need to log this in any of this columns if it is possible)?

Comment: [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036) might prove useful.

Comment: Bizarrely Oracle does not come with a built-in logging package for PL/SQL. You can write your own or you can use `logger` with is as close to de facto standard as there is. [Find out more](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger)